# Adding a http://www. to this regex and disallowing subdomains

Tags: regex

I've been using this regex to validate domain names, and it does really well. I need to add a `http://www.` or `https://www.`to it. I'm afraid I'll mess things up. It currently does not use a `http://www.`

Also, is there any way to bend this so it'll reject sub-domains?

So in all it'll be:

```
http://www.domain.com -> valid
www.domain.com - > Invalid (Should have the http://www. part)
http://sub.domain.com - > Invalid (Subdomain)
http://www.sub.domain.com -> Invlaid (Subdomain)
```

I tried doing things with the `http://www.` part, but ended with error. I'm clueless how to do the sub-domain reject part.

```
   function isurl($this_url)
    {
            if(preg_match("/^([a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+((a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz]|aero|arpa)|(b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz]|biz)|(c[acdfghiklmnorsuvxyz]|cat|com|coop)|d[ejkmoz]|(e[ceghrstu]|edu)|f[ijkmor]|(g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy]|gov)|h[kmnrtu]|(i[delmnoqrst]|info|int)|(j[emop]|jobs)|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|(m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz]|mil|mobi|museum)|(n[acefgilopruz]|name|net)|(om|org)|(p[aefghklmnrstwy]|pro)|qa|r[eouw]|s[abcdeghijklmnortvyz]|(t[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz]|travel)|u[agkmsyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw])$/i", $this_url)) 
                {
                return true;
                }

    }

    $this_url = "www.domain.com";

    if (isurl($this_url)) 
    {echo "Success";} 
    else 
    {echo "Fail";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mysite\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

or use this regx

```
/^(http?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

for perticular

```
   /^http?://([a-z0-9-]+\.)*blah\.com(/.*)?$/
```

Comment: I need this in a form verification script. Cant use htaccess for this.

Comment: @NullPointer Beware that this would also support `htt://` (As you're using the `?` on the `p` in `http`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php
    function isurl($this_url) {
        return (filter_var($this_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) && preg_match("#^https?://www\.#", $this_url));
    }
?>
```

using [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and a simple regex.

Comment: Ok. I'll explain. It has to be a regex.